# Installing a custom package in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, package

I have a project that I am working on and I am using some code from another project. There is a custom HTML.Helper Package that is called MicrosoftHelper. I copied this from one project to the other in the packages folder and them right clicked References to add the package. It is there and for some reason when I use the helper, it is like it does not see it. In the other project if I go to the helper in my code and view the definition it is in metadata. This project it is not. Is there something else that I need to do to get this into Metadata?

```
CS1061  'HtmlHelper<MenuPermission>' does not contain a definition for 'StarkAjaxFormSubmiter' and no 
extension method 'StarkAjaxFormSubmiter' accepting a first argument of type 
'HtmlHelper<MenuPermission>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MyProject
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I have done this. So I had to revisit a project and go back over everything. The solution to this is that I needed to add the namespace to the web.config. Inside the Views folder

```
<namespaces>
   // All other namespaces //
   <add namespace="MicrosoftHelper" />
</namespaces
```

This way I am able to use the HtmlHelpers in the views..